# Can “Case statement“ be safely used in a regular/prepared statement of JDBC?

Tags: sql, jdbc, case

In our software we use Postgresql as a database with the JDBC3 driver type. Our JDBC statements use SQL containing “Case statement“ .

Will this code work if we switch to another driver or database:

Example:

```
SELECT r.routineid, 
       r.routinetypeid, 
       CASE WHEN (pc.version=20 and pc.parentid>0) 
            THEN CASE WHEN (r.processed='t') 
                      THEN pc.processed ELSE r.processed 
                 END 
            ELSE r.processed 
       END AS processed, 
       CASE WHEN (r.version=2 and r.parentid>0) 
            THEN (SELECT m_req 
                    FROM routine 
                   WHERE routineid=r.parentid
                 ) 
            ELSE r.m_req 
       END AS m_req, 
       r.version 
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM routine 
         WHERE routinetypeid in (11,12) 
           AND (fbroutineid='130' OR fbroutineid='806')
       ) AS r 
       LEFT JOIN 
       routine pc 
       ON r.routineid=pc.parentid 
ORDER BY r.routinetypeid;
```

Comment: depends on how the `case` was built.

Comment: approximate SQl: SELECT r.routineid, r.routinetypeid, CASE WHEN (pc.version=20 and pc.parentid>0) THEN CASE WHEN (r.processed='t') THEN pc.processed ELSE r.processed END ELSE r.processed END AS processed, CASE WHEN (r.version=2 and r.parentid>0) THEN (SELECT m_req FROM routine WHERE routineid=r.parentid) ELSE r.m_req END AS m_req, r.version FROM (SELECT * FROM routine WHERE routinetypeid in (11,12) AND (fbroutineid='130' OR fbroutineid='806'))  AS r LEFT JOIN routine pc ON r.routineid=pc.parentid ORDER BY r.routinetypeid;

Comment: @anarinsky - Please edit your question to include that information, as statements in comments can be difficult to read (and make sure it's formatted appropriately, please).  `CASE` statements are pretty standard, so what you're showing _should_ work, although the entire query should probably be modified into something else... at minimum, I doubt the correlated sub-query in the `CASE` is doing you any performance favors.

Comment: Thank you, you answered what I asked. I know that subqueries  are not optimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` statement is standard SQL and supported by almost all databases  -- Oracle (except for the oldest versions), MySQL, SQL Server, DB2, Postgres, and all the Postgres derivatives.  The one exception that I can readily think of is MS Access, but I would recommend that you avoid that anyway.

So, if your concern is compatibility for different database engines, you should be safe with case statements.

Your query has a nested select in the `case` statement.  Different databases will handle this better or worse -- and I guess Postgres is on the worse side.

You can get around this by joining in a summarized table:

```
routine rparent
on rparent.routineid = r.parentid
```

And then using `rparent.mreq` instead of the subquery.

Comment: Thank you. We had a pronlem in Postgresql with Case and changing the driver.  The query became very slow until we removed the Case statement.  Is this problem common?